# How to use a Batch script to change file names within a folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

So i'm trying to get a script to change file names with in a folder. However, i need the file names to ascend within 001 to 000999. Ever time a file is added a number is assigned to it within the numbers of 001 to 000999. If that makes sense.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If `001` have _two_ zeros before the number and `000999` have _three_ zeros before the number, what is the rule to choose 2 or 3 zeros before the number?

Answer (score 0):

If this is done in ***one run*** here is a way. But this will count from *000001* to *999999* :

```
@Echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a $c=1

for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "$Newname=00000!$c!"
   echo ren "%%a" "!$Newname:~-6!%%~xa"
   set /a $c+=1
)
```

Remove the `echo`  if that's what you need.

Comment: It is simpler this way: `set $c=1000001` and inside the for: `echo ren "%%a" "!$c:~1!%%~xa"` & `set /a $c+=1`